# PieChart with Labels

Tags: wpf, vb.net, charts, wpftoolkit, pie-chart

I want to make LabeledPieCharts in WPF (Source: [Bea's Blog](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=438) )
I have downloaded the DemoProject and it runs. If I want to create a LabeledPieChart it fails with this Error:

```
The Tag "LabeledPieChart.Series" isn't in XML-Namespace "clr-namespace:Controls;assembly=Controls". Line 65 Position 14.
```

Here is my code:

```
<customControls:LabeledPieChart x:Name="labeledPieChart"
                                Title="Population of Puget Sound Cities"
                                Grid.Row="3"
                                Width="700"
                                Height="500"
                                BorderBrush="Gray">
    <customControls:LabeledPieChart.Series>
        <customControls:LabeledPieSeries x:Name="labeledPieSeries"
                                         DependentValuePath="Population"
                                         IndependentValuePath="Name"
                                         IsSelectionEnabled="True"
                                         ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                                         LabelDisplayMode="Auto"
                                         PieChartLabelItemTemplate="{StaticResource pieChartLabelDataTemplate}"
                                         PieChartLabelStyle="{StaticResource pieChartLabelStyle}" />
    </customControls:LabeledPieChart.Series>
</customControls:LabeledPieChart>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've downloaded the project and your code seems to work OK. Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794482/tag-does-not-exist-in-xml-namespace) will help you a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found the error. In the Project were 2 "control.dll"-files and they were different. One of them hasn't got the Property "Series"