# What is the proper way to update .NET Framework in a solution?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am new to C# and due to circumstances I have ended up being "in charge" of a big project.

This project consists in two solutions.

- **Solution A**: a library that will be used in solution B as NuGet package.
- **Solution B**: a Wpf application.

I am developing new stuff to solution A, and to use a feature from HttpClient I need to update .NET Framework from version 4.6.2 to 4.7.2.

I followed a lot of tutorials, searched a lot in stackoverflow and used the Microsft documentation, and I have understood that I need to change the "Target framework" from Solution A (The one implementing HttpClient) from 4.6.2 to 4.7.2, and then using the Package Manager console do  `Update-Package -Reinstall` to force all NuGet packages to update to this new .NET Framework version.

Solution A builds fine, but I get this warning in some point of the output:

```
'NU5128: Some target frameworks declared in the dependencies group of the nuspec and the lib/ref folder do not have exact matches in the other location. Consult the list of actions below:
  - Add a dependency group for .NETFramework4.7.2 to the nuspec'
```

But when I try to use this NuGet package in Solution B, I get a lot of strange errors that I think are caused due to a missmatch between .NET Framework target from both solutions:

```
error MC3074: The tag 'NullVisibilityConverter' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:WpfControlLibrary.Converters;assembly=WpfControlLibrary'. Line 23 Position 5.
error MC3066: The type reference cannot find a public type named 'HistogramWpf'. Line 17 Position 54.
error MC3074: The tag 'LineChart' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:WpfControlLibrary.Controls;assembly=WpfControlLibrary'. Line 38 Position 34.
error MC3066: The type reference cannot find a public type named 'DOutputDType'. Line 15 Position 56.
error MC3074: The tag 'HistogramWpf' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:WpfControlLibrary.Controls;assembly=WpfControlLibrary'. Line 24 Position 9.
error MC3074: The tag 'HistogramWpf' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:WpfControlLibrary.Controls;assembly=WpfControlLibrary'. Line 53 Position 30.
error MC3066: The type reference cannot find a public type named 'NlogViewer'. Line 33 Position 85.
error MC3066: The type reference cannot find a public type named 'HistogramWpf'. Line 194 Position 56.
error MC3074: The tag 'NullVisibilityConverter' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:WpfControlLibrary.Converters;assembly=WpfControlLibrary'. Line 7 Position 3.
error MC3066: The type reference cannot find a public type named 'ImageViewModel'. Line 45 Position 87.
```

And I've tried to update .NET Framework from solution B to v 4.7.2, but the error persists.

As stated in this post [Tag doesn't exist in namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41904176/7346509) it seems to be a compatibility problem between the projects, but I've checked all the project dependencies, and no one has the yellow triangle described **after** update .NET Framework at solution B.

What's going on? How can I securely achieve this update?

**EDIT:**

I used WinRar to open the .nupkg and I've checked that inside lib folder, I have two folders, one called Net462 that contains 9/10 dll from solution A, and other called Net472 that contains the last dll from solution A.

For some reason the .nupkg is not building well. I've tried to move the dlls to folder Net472 and now solution B builds fine, but I need to know how to generate correctly the solution A NuGet package.

**EDIT 2:**

After many restarts, a lot of clean solution, and removing the NuGet package and obj and bin folders, it magically started to generate the NuGet package well.

Now code builds, but when I click in Start button to launch the Wpf application I get a System.IO.FileNotFoundException saying:

> Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

The strange about that is that in my App.config or my packages.config, System.Runtime points to version 4.3.0.0, and I don't see any reference to System.Runtime 4.0.0.0.

This is the log error:

```
... Loaded ...WpfControlLibrary.dll. Symbols loaded.
... Loaded ...ControlzEx.dll. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
... Loaded ...GalaSoft.MvvmLight.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Managed Debugging Assistant 'BindingFailure' 
Error al cargar el ensamblado con el nombre para mostrar 'System.Runtime' en el contexto de enlace 'LoadFrom' de AppDomain con id. 1. Error debido a: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' ni una de sus dependencias. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.
```

Comment: It looks like Solution A produces a NuGet package, which is then used in Solution B. Is that correct? If so, then you need to update the **nuspec file** (which defines what goes into the NuGet package and what it's compatible with, more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec) to announce that the package supports or even requires `.NET Framework 4.7.2`.

Comment: I would use this tool: https://github.com/dotnet/try-convert - and say hello to the year 2021. :) - notice the tool will upgrade to the latest .net (core) version but you can than easily change the target framwork back, the reason why I would recommend the tool is, because it will update to package reference instead of packages.config, update the csproj to the new format

Comment: IMHO you should also consider moving straight to .net 6 instead of .net 4.7.2

Comment: @PeterB I edited my post, I've found something inside the .nupkg interesting. I will have a look at the link you gave me to check if I can solve the problem editing the nuspec file.

Comment: @RandRandom but can I update from .NET **Framework** 4.6.2 to the latest .NET **Core** without major implications? Sincerely I would love to use a tool that simplifies a bit (or a lot) these updates, but I am in big troubles trying to update from 4.6.2 to 4.7.2, and I cannot imagine the headaches of change from .NET Framework to .NET Core...

Comment: You don't have to update to .net core, the tool is aimed to help you to transision to .net core (now only called .net), but let the tool do its job and then simply open the csproj file and change it to what ever you want. - I am recommending it because it will just do more and open the way to a transision to .net 6 in the future if you wish to go that route. as I mentioned to update to the new sdk csproj file format and the package references.

Comment: (cont) as well as the automatic nuspec file generation, as is pointed out in the MSDN link provided by peter b - `A .nuspec file is not required to create packages for SDK-style projects`

Comment: @RandRandom ok so it seems I misunderstood what you tried to tell me the first time. I will have a look at this tool, thank you.

Comment: Make sure you do clean builds.  Net 4.7.2 fixed all compatibility issues with Core for TLS compatibility.  So with 4.7.2 you must use either TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3.  SSL, TLS 1.0, and TLS 1.1 will not work.  So make sure you change from HTTP to HTTPS (secure).  You also may need to make sure certificates are loaded on you clients.

Comment: After wasting a lot of hours, it "magically" started to build. As I mentioned in the post at the edit, the NuGet was not being generated correctly. For some reason, after many restarts, many clean solution, and things like that, started to build correctly.